# Which substring of the string1 matches with the string2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string-matching

There are two strings.

`String str1="Order Number Order Time Trade Number";`

`String str2="Order Tm";` Then I want to know that **str2** matches with which substring in the **str1.**

```
string regex = Regex.Escape(str2.Replace(@"\ ", @"\s*");
bool isColumnNameMatched = Regex.IsMatch(str1, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I am using regex because "Order Tm" will also matches "Order Time".It gives bool value that matches occurred or not.

Like `str2="Order Tm"` then it should return like in the **str1,Order Time** is the substring where matches is occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very unclear and your code does not compile.
There are some problems:

1. You replace `"\ "` with `@"\s*"` - but you should replace just `" "` without `\`
2. You can't use `Regex.Escape()` this way. It will double your `\` and result in another regex which is not working. For instance your `\s*` will become `\\s*`
3. It seems that you want to match only one word (that's where your question is unclear). In this case you should match against something like `"Order|Tm"`
4. To get the matched word you need a [grouping construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx):

Example:

```
var str1 = "Order Number Order Time Trade Number";
var str2 = "(Order|Tm)";
string regex = str2.Replace( @" ", @"\s*" );
var match = Regex.Match( str1, regex );

match.Success; // results in "true"
match.Value; // results in "Order"
```

Comment: @tanascius,thank you sir,but I can not understand why there is Order|Tm ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: That is an `alternation construct`. You can have a look at the liked url for it. It means that your regex matches either `Order` _or_ `Tm`

Comment: Ok Sir I understood it,if there is string like buy/sell and then how can I match buy-sell to that string ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: when you need to match different characters you can use `.`, like: `buy.sell`. The `.` will match any character, so both, `buy/sell` and `buy-sell` will be matched